# PayPal DoExpressPayment Fails in Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, session-state, paypal

I'm absolutely desperate, but first let me say that this site is invaluable to developers with a wealth of top quality information!
Having 'lurked' on the site harvesting information for years I have come across a problem this site and no other has resolved so far.
I am probably missing something so obvious that no one mentions it!
Simplistically, I have a web page connecting to PayPal express which goes to PayPal but comes back into a new session instead of the originating session, and therefore fails with the common order total missing, which basically means the session data is not there.
I created a database version of the session, and notice that on PayPal entry a session with a copy of all the data was created, but with IE a new exact copy of the session was created (so now two identical sessions in the database) and it works… However in Firefox the second session was a new session with no data, hence the failure..

The start of my PayPal process script is (without databas)

```
<?php
  session_start(); // start initial session 
  require_once('../Connections/DataWebDA.php');
  include_once("config-pp.php");
  include_once("paypal.class.php");
  $problem = false;
if($_POST) //Post Data received from product list page.
```

{ this initialses and goes to payment login etc..)

On return from PayPal

```
<?php
  session_start(); // start initial session 
  $sesid = session_id(); 
  require_once('../Connections/DataWebDA.php');
  include_once("config-pp.php");
  include_once("paypal.class.php");
  $problem = false;
//Paypal redirects back to this page using ReturnURL, We should receive TOKEN and Payer ID
if(isset($_GET["token"]) && isset($_GET["PayerID"]))
{
    if (isset($_SESSION))
```

Originally the script was in one file, but I have split into two in order to clarify the session operation.. This still works in IE(11) not in Firefox, Chrome and I expect any other browser.
I have gone round and round trying to call a named session adding the session id to the incoming post but with no success.
If needed I can elaborate on the details, however it maybe that someone has experienced this already and can point me in the right direction..

Comment: I don't think sessions are the right way to do this. I last worked with integrating PayPal about 18 months ago, and what I did then was when passing the user over to PayPal, I included all the required data in the `custom` field, separated by underscores, then when this data was passed back, I split it using the underscores and pulled out the customer's ID.

Comment: Thanks Matthew... for fast reply and your comments, I will look at that later, needed to go onto other tasks as this was stopping me from getting other work done! So I will revisit it shortly and update you on my findings. Its interesting that you rejected sessions and used an alternatve means. I have not seen any reference to a custom field yet. I will look further into that.

Comment: IIRC I used http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration to help with PayPal integration.

Comment: Thanks again,Mathew... I will look into this, still catching up with my backlog, and this will take me a while to study. This is first time I have used a site to ask a question and get any response. Quite a bit of responsibility on me to bring it to a conclusion. So if it takes a day or to, it's not for lack of interest the job has to be completed and this part has to work .

Comment: Looking at site you mentioned.. I will work on that. My script was based on http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php.

Comment: HI Matthew (sorry spelt your name wrong earlier). That link script certainly works although for IPN payment rather than express payments.. However I am sure I can work around that, didn't originally use IPN as PayPal state its not always instant. It appears that the data is posted back to my script instead of via session which the other script used! So thank you for the help.. (I need to acknowledge your answer in some way now), first time so I will need to find out how to do that. Regards Brian.